# Input validation with regular expression not working

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a game in which, Starting of the game I have to ask the user for '**How many times he wants to play**' and the user input must be an integer.
So I write the code I shared below. But it doesn't work as I expected.
If anyone can help me to figure out what I did wrong it will be helpful to me.
Thanks in advance.

```js
let playCount = 0;
let regxNum = /^[0-9]+$/g; //Regular Expression to select all numbers between 0-9.
let checkPlayCount = 0;
let askPlayCount = () => { //Function to get game play count.
  checkPlayCount = 0;
  playCount = Number(prompt("How many times you want to play: ")); //Gets play count and convert into number;
  checkPlayCount = Array.from(String(playCount), Number); //Converts number into array
}

askPlayCount();

//Code for validating input : must be number.
for(let i = 0; i < checkPlayCount.length; i++){
  if(checkPlayCount[i] != regxNum){
    console.log("Please enter valid input");
    askPlayCount();
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you converting to an array? You could just convert the input to a number and check if it `isNaN()`.

Comment: 001 you are correct converting to array is not needed. I added the solution in the answer @mr.Hritik you can check there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you convert the number into the array, while you simply can do this by directly checking the input against regex. Here is my version of the problem

```js
let playCount = 0;
let regxNum = /^[0-9]+$/; // Regular Expression to match all numbers between 0-9

let askPlayCount = () => {
  playCount = Number(prompt("How many times do you want to play: "));
}

askPlayCount();

// Code for validating input: must be a number.
while (!regxNum.test(playCount)) {
  console.log("Please enter a valid input");
  askPlayCount();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just convert the input to a number and check if it `Number.isInteger()`

```js
let askPlayCount = () => {
    let number;
    do {
        number = Number(prompt("How many times you want to play: "));
    } while (!Number.isInteger(number) || number <= 0);
    return number;
}

//Code for validating input : must be number.
let playCount = askPlayCount();
```